# How to access a specific dictionary via user input?

Tags: python, dictionary, input

I have defined two dictionaries `dict1` and `dict2`. I want the user to tell me via input, which dictionary to access (of course he has to know the exact names), so he gets a value from this dictionary. The following doesn't work out, I get a

> Type Error "string indices must be integers":

```
dict1 = {'size': 38.24, 'rate': 465}
dict2 = {'size': 32.9, 'rate': 459}

name = input('Which dictionary to access?: ')
ret = name['size']
print ('Size of ' + name + ' is ' + str(ret))
```

Comment: name is a string value not the dict

Comment: Can you indicate if you work with Python 2 or 3 ? The meaning of `input()` is different in both cases

Comment: I use Python 3.

Comment: Put your dicts in a dict as per the linked duplicate. Messing with variable variable names is an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
dict1 = {'size': 38.24, 'rate': 465}
dict2 = {'size': 32.9, 'rate': 459}

name = input('Which dictionary to access?: ')

if name == 'dict1':
  ret = dict1['size']
eif name == 'dict2':
  ret = dict2['size']


print ('Size of ' + name + ' is ' + str(ret))
```

or

```
   input_to_dict_mapping = {'dict1':dict1,'dict2':dict2}
   ret = input_to_dict_mapping[name]['size']
```

or from Antwane response.

**Updated**

```
input_to_dict_mapping = globe()
ret = input_to_dict_mapping[name]['size']
```

The problem is that `name is a string value`. you can not do the index as we do it in Dict.

Comment: But is there a possibility to turn that string into something that I can use, to access the dictionary?

Comment: yes and see the updated section. as Antwane pointed, You can use globe and get the dict and use it as mentioned in updated section

Answer (score 0):

`globals()` return a dict containing all global variables already defined:

```
>>> globals()
{'dict1': {'rate': 465, 'size': 38.24}, 'dict2': {'rate': 459, 'size': 32.9}, '__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__file__': 'C:/Users/xxx/.PyCharm2018.3/config/scratches/scratch.py', '__package__': None, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None}
```

So you should be able to retrieve the right variable using `globals()[name]`. But keep in mind this is a terrible way to do: variable names aren't meant to be dynamic. You should use a global dict to perform this kind of processing:

```
dicts = {
    "dict1": {'size': 38.24, 'rate': 465},
    "dict2": {'size': 32.9, 'rate': 459},
}

name = input('Which dictionary to access?: ')
ret = dicts[name]

print ('Size of ' + name + ' is ' + str(ret))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think this is the best and smartest solution.